How to make sure that the telegram bot does not spam after restarting, aiogram 3
I'm a beginner. I have a telegram bot, it is written in aiogram 3, python. The problem is that if the bot goes down and the user continues to send messages to it, then when the bot is restarted, it starts spamming, responding to commands set during inactivity. Is there any way to fix this? Well, so that as soon as I start the bot again, it "forgets" all those messages?

Why does bot reply to messages, that where sent while he was inactive · python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot · Discussion #3806 - maybe aiogram has also drop_pendinge_updates

maybe you could compare message time with time when you restarted bot - and skip messages.

Consider using the following method & parameter before starting bot polling to drop all the incoming updates the bot gets:
await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)

